# What SQL user is used by TFS to send alerts?

Tags: sql-server, tfs

We are running into a few issues with our TFS installation (TFS 2013 Update 4, SQL 2014 Standard) as a result of email alerts.  Most notably, Work Items cannot be created, because this triggers an email.

Any time a process or user attempts to create a Work Item, the error

```
TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.
```

is received.  Further, when I check the Event Viewer on the server, I can see the error and it reports that the inner exception is:

```
Exception Message: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. (type SqlException)
```

I have worked with the DBA and we have enabled Email Alerts on the server.  We have verified that, in general, the alerts work by using the test button on the administration console.  I can also set up a check-in alert through the web interface and receive said alerts without issue.  This seems to be specifically affecting Work Item creation alerts (which apparently are just automatically and irrevocably enabled).

Presumably, we could correct this by giving appropriate permissions to use that stored procedure.  To do so, we need to know what user to give permissions to.  So far we have tried giving execute permissions to my AD user, the service account used by the build service, and the Network Service account (which appears to be the TFS Service Account).

There is no indication in any error message as to what user is being used to execute that procedure.  So, my question:  What SQL user is used to send alerts when creating Work Items?

Edit:
For the record, this started working of its own accord.  We decided Monday to call Microsoft to get this fixed.  Before that happened, failed builds magically created some work items (on Tuesday, a full day after we gave up), and we are now able to create work items.  Everyone involved states not doing anything.  We are baffled, but in a good way.

Comment: Have you tried checking a profiler trace?

Comment: @TabAlleman No, did not even occur to us.  DBA states too busy just at the moment, but should have it done by EOB.

Comment: Profiler trace was unhelpful. The user name returned with the error (we never saw the command) was obfuscated (the S-n-n-nnnnnn junk you sometimes see in the registry). It looked like maybe it was a generic user, and we tried making that user a sysadmin, but did not work.

Comment: You need to raise a suport ticket with Microsoft, but I suspect your TFS environment is miss-configured. Follow the documentation or contact a consultant. The permission requirements are explicit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to advise you that a DBA should not be making changes to the TFS databases.  I suggest opening a ticket with MSFT and getting assistance from the product support group.

Comment: No changes have been made to the database. I have an open thread on the issue on the MSDN forums, but this site is often faster when there is a specific question.

Comment: Your question states several things that you tried.  Are those not change to the database?  I'm being serious here. MSFT doesn't support any SQL access to the database including SELECT operations.  Be very careful to not get yourself into an unsupported scenario.  At a minimum take a backup of the database and restore it into a sandbox environment using documented procedures and do your testing there.  I run TFS for a fortune 50 company and  I can tell you from personal experience that the developer support team backed up with escalations to the product team was instrumental to fixing problems

Comment: The only thing that counts as a change to the TFS database is turning on alerts. But that was accomplished through the Microsoft provided interface using instructions from a Microsoft created website. The permission changes were done to msdb, as that is where the sp_send_dbmail proc exists.

Comment: Dave, it sounds like your SQL server has not been configured according to the TFS documentation. I would recommend following procedure.